# Передать GET переменную файлу который подключаем через include или require_once

Tags: php

Приветствую всех

Представьте себе обычные include в php или require_once. Как в "подключенный" файл передать GET переменные? (Через сессию конечно можно.. если не открыто несколько вкладок проблем ен будет, а вот если открыто - вариант не катит)

з.ы. Господа, ответ нет - тоже ответ. Или я чтото не так спросил?

Comment: >Или я чтото не так спросил?

именно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_GET`, он и в подключенном файле `$_GET`.

*Или я что-то не так ответил?*

Comment: Ответил бы комментом :) пофлудили бы пока сам ТС не догадался об ответе.

Comment: Эх, момент упущен. Но вопросов для этого дела еще хватит :)

Comment: Не догадался бы точно, ну хоть ответ услышал